# File force compatibilty with download count module

Tags: files

I am using File Force Download 7.x-1.2+0-dev module with Download Count module. If when i set manage display for file field as File Force: Generic file then it is counting download twice but if i set Generic file with download count then it works fine.how to avoid counting download twice with generic file.